# Postgres: Create Column and Update Column Values with Query Output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a file that has no Primary Key. In order to load the file and perform analysis I want to concatenate 2 existing columns and send the output to a new column. I'm then going to do a hash of this resultant column and use that as a PK.

I haven't even got to the hash part as I can not for the life of me work out how to populate my concatenated column with data.

The query I'm trying to use is:

```
ALTER TABLE members_250815
ADD COLUMN email_id VARCHAR;
UPDATE members_250815
INSERT INTO members_250815(email_id)(
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY[emailaddress, id], ' ') AS email_id
FROM members_250815);
```

As seperate queries both

```
ALTER TABLE members_250815
ADD COLUMN email_id VARCHAR;
```

and

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY[emailaddress, id], ' ') AS email_id
FROM members_250815;
```

seem to work as I want them to (ie -  1) create the new column and 2) concatenate the 2 columns) however my issue seems to be in joining it all together.

Am I doing something really stupid? I have tried to research this for hours but I am getting nowhere. Essentially the task I am trying to achieve is:

```
Create new column on existing table
Concatenate 2 existing columns
```

Take the result of the concatenation and update this new column with this data without affecting any of my other existing data.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance

---Update 260815

Many thanks for the quick advice guys, much appreciated! 
Using a combination of your advice I have gotten to here:

```
CREATE TABLE members_update AS 
SELECT * FROM members_250815;

ALTER TABLE members_update
   ADD COLUMN email_id VARCHAR;<br/>

UPDATE members_update
SET email_id = email || id;

ALTER TABLE members_update
   ADD COLUMN hashed_primary_key VARCHAR;

UPDATE members_update
SET hashed_primary_key = md5(email_id::VARCHAR);

ALTER TABLE members_update
   ADD CONSTRAINT hashed_primary_key_urn
   PRIMARY KEY (hashed_primary_key);

ANALYSE members_update;
```

I have checked and everything works as expected up until adding the primary key. This is because it turned out that my email field contains numerous NULL values which are then carried into to the email_id and hashed columns and stop the hashed version from being used as the PK.

As such I have been experimenting with IF THEN ELSE and WHERE ELSE statements like

```
UPDATE members_update(
   IF email IS NOT NULL
   THEN SET email_id = email || id
   ELSE SET email_id = id
   END IF);
```

I have tried numerous combinations, with and without brackets etc and I can never get it to work! I think I am close but just can't seem to make this final part work - has anyone got any ideas?

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: Hello mmTmmR welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and 
[**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ah sorry, I haven't heard of SQLFiddle, I'll read the rules before making another post. Thanks :)

Comment: I fix my answer to include your new update requirement. Just wonder why you create a hash  instead just a serial key as I show in my sample?

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for replying! I have actually done the Serial column as a temporary solution so I can mess around with the data. The reason I need to do the hash of the concatenated column is because that will be the format in the future so I was just trying to work out how to get everything in the correct format now so it doesn't bite me in the future! Will let you know how i get on - Thanks again!

Comment: Two things, when you talk to someone include the character `@username`  that way the person get a notification. Also if you start line with 4 spaces your text will appear in `code` format. That is how I update your code. And last if my last correction fix your update request please consider accept my answer.

Comment: btw if `email` is null  and you use id to create the PK is there a chance appear repeat ID? That can cause problem because with duplicated ID that field can't be PK. And if all ID are different then that should be the PK column and no need to create a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your [**update**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) statement is wrong

You need `SET`,  and [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181765(v=sql.120).aspx) Should be:

```
ALTER TABLE members_250815
    ADD COLUMN email_id VARCHAR;

UPDATE members_250815
SET email_id = CASE 
                   WHEN email IS NULL THEN id
                   ELSE email || id
               END;
```

`ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY[emailaddress, id], ' ')` may also work, but a further research will be necesarry to know if is more eficient than just concatenate the string.

**Better way to create an PK column:**
Just alter the table and add a serial column

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d23f0)

```
CREATE TABLE members_250815
    ("DMDUNIT" varchar(5), 
     "IND" int)
;

INSERT INTO members_250815 VALUES ('TM001', 1);
INSERT INTO members_250815 VALUES ('TM002', 1);
INSERT INTO members_250815 VALUES ('TM003', 1);

ALTER TABLE members_250815
ADD COLUMN id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

**Aditional Info**

In postgres updates are very slow. So in some cases is better consider just create a new table:

```
CREATE new_table AS 
    SELECT *, CASE 
                   WHEN email IS NULL THEN id
                   ELSE email || id
              END as email_id
    FROM members_250815
```

and then

```
DROP TABLE IF EXITS members_250815;
ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO members_250815
```

Comment: Use `||` not `+` for string concatenation. Or preferably, use `format(...)` with `%s` placeholders.

Comment: Why do you think that in Postgres "updates are very slow"?  And the select statement for a `create table as` does not need to be put in parentheses.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I fixed I probably was writing CTE, but when you say doesn't need you mean is an error or just extra chars? Regarding the slow update I read several document where say updates in postgres are treat with one delete + insert. So is much faster just create the table again.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza many thanks for your solution - it worked a treat! Really really appreciate it. PS apologies for not replying sooner, I have been away on a long weekend for the Bank Holiday.